# Django - Set what model for data type geometry(MultiPolygon) in database?

Tags: python, django

In my database, I have a column like this: (Around 2000 letters)

```
  Geo
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
```

Data type of this column is `geometry(MultiPolygon)`

I dont know what to assign for this column in `model` of Django

Right now I set  `models.TextField()`

Comment: What comes close to mind is geoDjango's MultiPolygonField ...you can try that

Comment: @josephthomaa I dont think MultiPolygonField do not exists for models since I got this `AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'MultiPolygonField'`